# How to speed up Rust function to search through a large JSON file

Tags: json, search, rust

Currently I have a Rust function that searches through a large JSON file (About 1,080,000 lines) Currently this function takes about 1 second to search through this file, the data in this file is mostly stuff like this:

`{"although":false,"radio":2056538449,"hide":1713884795,"hello":1222349560.787047,"brain":903780409.0046091,"heard":-1165604870.8374772}`

How would I be able to increase the performance of this function?

Here is my `Main.rs` file.

```
use std::collections::VecDeque;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::BufWriter;
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader, Write};

fn search(filename: &str, search_line: &str) -> Result<VecDeque<u32>, std::io::Error> {
    let file = File::open(filename)?;
    let mut reader = BufReader::with_capacity(2048 * 2048, file);
    let mut line_numbers = VecDeque::new();
    let mut line_number = 0;
    let start = std::time::Instant::now();
    loop {
        line_number += 1;
        let mut line = String::new();
        let n = reader.read_line(&mut line)?;
        if n == 0 {
            break;
        }
        if line.trim() == search_line {
            line_numbers.push_back(line_number);
            println!(
                "Matching line found on line number {}: {}",
                line_number, line
            );
                    break;
        }
    }
    let elapsed = start.elapsed();
    println!("Elapsed time: {:?}", elapsed);
    if line_numbers.is_empty() {
        println!("No lines found that match the given criteria");
    }
    Ok(line_numbers)
}

fn main() {
    let database = "Test.json";
    if let Err(e) = search(database, r#"{"08934":420696969}"#) {
        println!("Error reading file: {}", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you running in release mode? You don't do anything with the `line_numbers` vec except see if its empty. You could also avoid allocating `line` every iteration.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo I ran it in release mode, and that helped a lot, could you direct me to a resource that could help me avoid allocating line every iteration?

Comment: `let mut line = String::new();loop{ line.clear(); ...}` just don't do it inside the loop.

Comment: Using the [`regex`](https://docs.rs/regex) crate may prove faster, it has a lot of optimizations.